# Changing div contents (jQuery .html) from php functions

Tags: php, jquery

I am looking to update a progress message in a div as various php functions are called.

jQuery and jQueryUi loaded here...

css for div:

```
.progress {
height: 40px;
width : 100%;
}
```

html for div:
Initially empty

```
<div class = "progress"></div>
```

php :
each function is called in turn from the main body of the php file and the div content is inserted with jQuery .html()

```
upload();
process_file();
save_file();

function upload{
    echo '<script>  $(".progress").html("Uploading file");</script>';
    .... rest of upload processing
    }
function process_file{
    echo '<script>  $(".progress").html("Processing file");</script>';
    .... rest of file processing
    }
function save_file{
   echo '<script>  $(".progress").html("Saving file");</script>';
   .... rest of file saving
    }
```

Obviously this won't work as php can't "see" the jquery (or vise versa). The div is updated, but only with the last call "Saving File" and only after the script is finished.

So the question is: how (or if) this can be done.
The upload and process_file scripts can take quite some time to complete (processing uploaded images with imageMagick) and I'd like to be able to update the div with the current state of the processing.

Comment: Poor structure. You should be using ajax calls and then processing the returned data to execute appropriate commands. I.e. if my app responds with {"message": "Saving File"} then I'm simply doing $(".progress").html(data.message); If you need to check the status multiple times then you simply run an ajax call on a timeout until it's complete. If you need the live progress of a file upload you will need to install the appropriate php module (i.e. http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress)

Comment: Yes, I know it's poor structure. Just an outline of what I'm trying to do. I didn't think it was possible to use ajax in that direction: PHP->AJAX->jQuery(update div>. Is that what you mean?